# run the python program using existing conda environment as a python interpreter

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, conda

Within VScode, I am using an existing conda environment to run the Python program. I use the "python: select interpreter" to select an existing conda environment. After running, the code works just fine. However, the terminal gives the following message. Should that be a concern, or how can I remove these messages.

```
conda : The term 'conda' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was   
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Comment: exactly how and to exactly where did you install conda? Is that directory in your system `PATH`?

Comment: The VSCode terminal may not run shell in a login mode by default. You need to configure this.